# How to Subtract daily sale in the inventory and Show daily bases Stock list using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Stock Table

```
       Date    StoreNo Code  productQty
    2015-06-02  61     1     -1
    2015-06-02  61     2     -2
    2015-06-03  61     1     -3
```

Table#inventroy

```
    Date      StoreNo Code  productQty
    2015-06-01  61     1     33
    2015-06-01  61     2     100
    2015-06-02  61     1     32
    2015-06-02  61     2     98
    2015-06-03  61     1     33
    2015-06-03  61     2     100
    2015-06-04  61     1     31
    2015-06-04  61     2     100
    2015-06-05  61     1     33
    2015-06-05  61     2     100
    2015-06-06  61     1     33
    2015-06-06  61     2     99
```

i did union all inventory and sale

```
Select 
                                    P.StoreNo
                                    ,p.Date
                                    ,p.ProductBarCode
                                    ,Sum (ProductQty) As productQty
                      from
                       (Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty From #inventory
                       Union all
                       Select StoreNo,Date,ProductBarCode,ProductQty from #sale  )p   
                              Group By p.StoreNo,p.Date,p.ProductBarCode
```

OutPut should be Like

```
    Date      StoreNo Code  productQty
    2015-06-01  61     1     33
    2015-06-01  61     2     100
    2015-06-02  61     1     32
    2015-06-02  61     2     98
    2015-06-03  61     1     29
    2015-06-03  61     2     98
    2015-06-04  61     1     30
    2015-06-04  61     2     98
    2015-06-05  61     1     30
    2015-06-05  61     2     98
    2015-06-06  61     1     30
    2015-06-06  61     2     97
```

I want to show everyday inventory - sale on daily bases !! but i dont know how to do !

I tried This method 
But some of data are missing from sale table when join with inventory ..

```
SELECT                                                                                StoreName ,p.Date as Date
 ,p.ProductBarCode as ProductBarCode                                                            ,isnull(i.productqty-(select ProductQty as runningsum from #Stock st where st.date<=i.date and st.storeno=i.storeno and st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode ),i.productqty) as ProductQty

  From #inventory i
   LEFT JOIN Store S ON S.StoreNo = i.StoreNo 
   Left JOIN #Stock st ON st.StoreNo = i.StoreNo and st.ProductBarCode = i.ProductBarCode and st.Date = i.Date
```

Comment: *I want to show everyday inventory = sale on daily bases !!* Can you elaborate on this. I didn't get the logic

Comment: Still its not clear! Why for `2015-06-02` productQty didnt change and why for `2015-06-03` productQty got changed

Comment: Can you explain the logic? Still not understanding the logic...

Comment: @Prdp :: modified

Comment: @KannanKandasamy:: modified

Comment: @mad Show `#stock` table too